# Is it possible to develop flutter windows desktop with fcm push notification?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

I was thinking to developing a windows desktop application with dart and flutter but i don't know how can i integrate Firebase cloud messaging with it. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no Windows desktop support in the firebase_messaging flutter packages. There was a separate effort to develop desktop support for some of the firebase platform that Google had announced in partnership with a company called Invertase, however I haven't heard much about that in the past 6 months and I don't believe that messaging is at the top of the priority list (I know, I want it too)

It looks like the project is still [alive and seeing regular commits](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_desktop) but for now my suggestion would be, unless you want to use the C++ SDK and develop your own plugin, you might want to curb plans for native Windows push notifications for a little while. (If you decide to make your own plugin, let me know, because again, I want it too!)